# How can I shorten my code with isset checks and error setting

Tags: php

I have already created a separate iscorrect method for code conciseness, but this is the limit of my skills. I hope to shorten the code within checkDataCorrectness() even more. Help

Heres model that has iscorrect method

```
namespace application\core;

use application\lib\Db;
use application\lib\Auth;

abstract class Model 
{
    public array $route;
    public string $error;

    /*  Other methods  */

    public function isCorrect(string $data, 
        int $lengthFrom = null, 
        int $lengthTo = null, 
        $regex = null,
        $image = null,
    ) {
        if (isset($image)) {
            if (is_uploaded_file['tmp_name'] and getimagesize['tmp_name']) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        } else {
            $lenght = strlen($data);
            $correctStartLength = isset($lengthFrom) ? $lenght >= $lengthFrom : true;
            $correctEndLength = isset($lengthTo) ? $lenght <= $lengthTo : true;
            $correctReg = isset($regex) ? preg_match($regex, $data) : true;
            return $correctStartLength and $correctEndLength and $correctReg;
        }
    }
}
```

And there's Account extending Model. I want to shorten checkDataCorrectness() method and maybe the errors property adjacent to it.

```
namespace application\models;

use application\core\Model;

class Account extends Model
{
    private array $errors = [
        'incorrectName' => 'Ошибка. Имя должно быть до 30 символов',
        'incorrectLastName' => 'Ошибка. Фамилия должна быть до 30 символов',
        'incorrectAddress' => 'Ошибка. Адрес должен быть до 100 символов',
        'incorrectVkUrl' => 'Ошибка. Неверный формат ссылки VK',
        'incorrectSteamUrl' => 'Ошибка. Неверный формат ссылки Steam',
        'incorrectBio' => 'Ошибка. Биография должна содержать до 600 символов',
        'incorrectImage' => 'Файл не является изображением',
        'noUser' => 'Пользователя не существует',
    ];

    /*  Other methods  */

    public function checkDataCorrectness()
    {
        if (isset($_POST['name']) and !$this->isCorrect($_POST['name'], 
            lengthTo:30)) {
            $this->error = $this->errors['incorrectName'];
            return false;
        }
        if (isset($_POST['last_name']) and !$this->isCorrect($_POST['last_name'], 
            lengthTo:30)) {
            $this->error = $this->errors['incorrectLastName'];
            return false;
        }
        if (isset($_POST['address']) and !$this->isCorrect($_POST['address'], 
            lengthTo:100)) {
            $this->error = $this->errors['incorrectAddress'];
            return false;
        }
        $regex_vk = "#(https:\/\/)?(vk.com\/)([a-zA-Z0-9]+)#mi";
        if (isset($_POST['vk_url']) and !$this->isCorrect($_POST['vk_url'], 
            regex:$regex_vk)) {
            $this->error = $this->errors['incorrectVkUrl'];
            return false;
        }
        $regex_steam = "#(?<CUSTOMPROFILE>https?\:\/\/steamcommunity.com\/id\/[A-Za-z_0-9]+)|(?<CUSTOMURL>\/id\/[A-Za-z_0-9]+)|(?<PROFILE>https?\:\/\/steamcommunity.com\/profiles\/[0-9]+)|(?<STEAMID2>STEAM_[10]:[10]:[0-9]+)|(?<STEAMID3>\[U:[10]:[0-9]+\])|(?<STEAMID64>[^\/][0-9]{8,})#";
        if (isset($_POST['steam_url']) 
            and !$this->isCorrect($_POST['steam_url'], regex:$regex_steam)) {
            $this->error = $this->errors['incorrectSteamUrl'];
            return false;
        }
        if (isset($_POST['biography']) 
            and !$this->isCorrect($_POST['biography'], lengthTo:600)) {
            $this->error = $this->errors['incorrectBio'];
            return false;
        }
        if (isset($_FILES['image']) 
            and !$this->isCorrect(image: $_FILES['image'])) {
            $this->error = $this->errors['incorrectImage'];
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want refactoring advice you might be better to ask at the Code Review stackexchange. Here we mostly deal with bugs/problems in code which isn't working properly. Check their on-topic guidance before posting though, obviously.

Comment: A small optimization: Use `return bool_expression;` instead of `if (bool_expression) return true; else return false;` .

Comment: Do not use `and` keyword, use `&&` instead.

Comment: The pattern in `checkDataCorrectness` is actually pretty common. You _could_ try to "optimize" it by building a structure/pattern, like maybe an array of objects or magic keys that store error keys and validation patterns, but you'd be adding potentially more complexity by doing that, too. If it just just 7 fields, and they aren't shared elsewhere, I wouldn't overthink this too much.

Comment: My main advice would be to return all validation errors at one, rather than forcing users to fix them one by one. You also seem to be using ternary operator (`?:`) for the sake of using it. Other than that, code verbosity is largely a matter of taste.